# TikZ: Omit {} after \node declaration for unlabelled node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

This may seem a bit trivial, but I am writing TikZ code with an enormous number of unlabelled nodes. It frustrates me that I have to type `{}` at the end of every node declaration. Is there some straightforward way to avoid having to type this? Omitting the `{}` gives a compilation error: `A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `node contents` option can be used instead of the curley braces.

You can apply it to all nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    every node/.append style = {
        node contents =,
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[fill=red];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or you can define a custom style that you apply to all nodes in question:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    notext/.style = {
        node contents =,
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[notext, fill=red];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

See [TikZ documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) page 215.

Please note that "When the option [`node contents`] is used inside the options of a node, the parsing of the node stops immediately after the end of the option block."

But it is still possible to name a node with the `name` option.

Answer (score 11):

The `{}` are part of the internal used syntax and can't be avoided (just replaced by `\bgroup \egroup`, but that doesn't help you).

If your `\node`s don't have any content and size and are only used to store the coordinates, then I would use `\coordinate` instead (or `\path coordinate`). It is basically a `\node` without content. IIRC it uses `\node [..] {};` internally.

Alternatively just write your own macro which inserts the correct `\node` syntax itself.

Comment: Such a macro could be something as simple as `\def\nod [#1]{\node[#1] {} }`. You can then write `\nod [draw=red];` instead of `\node[draw=red] {};`.